# How to enable decoding for specific Python class?

Tags: python, unicode, flask, python-2.x, python-unicode

I have following code:

```
return render_template(
        'sample.html',
        title=('Härre').decode('utf-8'),
        year=datetime.now().year,
        message = ("Härre guut").decode('utf-8')
    )
```

Above code is working fine. But I want to know is it possible to enable automatic decoding for special characters for specific class? So that my code becomes like this:

```
return render_template(
        'sample.html',
        title=('Härre'),
        year=datetime.now().year,
        message = ("Härre guut")
    )
```

If yes then how it is done?

In my case special character is letter ä, and it can be decoded with utf-8.

I have tried to to add following line at first line of my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

However that won't help. I get following error if I try to enable above line and take out all `decode('utf-8')` parts:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 12: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Which is very clear error. It tries to use 'ascii' codec to decode special characters of the code.

If you wonder why I want to enable such functionality, the answer is that in future I'm going to have more `render_template()` method. This method is used with Flask framework.

Comment: Is it Python2? Please add [python-3.x] or [python-2.x] tag to your question.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus: It is Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the risk of being too trivial, you could make this decoding automatic by using Python 3, which uses Unicode instead of ascii.

Otherwise, as Brandon indicated, you do have to take pains with Python 2 to appropriately decode you inputs, use Unicode within your program, prefacing strings awing 'u', and the encoding when you output data, usually to utf-8, but whatever is appropriate for you.

Decoding and encoding at the "the edges" and using Unicode in between, is a lot of work, but necessary. It's a good reason to make the switch to Python 3. :-)

Comment: I would have used it but there are few limitations why I have to use older. It's little bit complex to explain :). But I have now to endure the pain of using decode() or try using the suggestion of @NotAnAmbiTurner. Thank you for you too :)

Comment: @Amir: to get unicode literals on Python 2, it is enough to add `from __future__ import unicode_literals` at the top of the module where you want that behavior (the alternative is to mark each individual string with `u''` but it is easier to do the opposite i.e., add `b''` to binary data if necessary). You don't need to change Python version just for that (though it is at least useful to test individual modules on Python 3 (if your application allows to write single source Python 2/3 compatible code)).

Comment: Nice J.F. Sebastian; I'll be using that in the future when I need cross-version compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

If you're only talking about string which you are typing, I'd try putting a `u` in front of them (eg. `u'string'`). The `u` tells python the string is unicode. I've used that successfully in similar circumstances in the past.

Also, according to the [flask docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/unicode/) (way at the bottom), to use that `# -*- coding: ...` bit properly, you have to set your text editor to UTF-8, otherwise it's saving in `ascii`, which might be why you're still getting that error.

Comment: yup, but this is supposed to be *answer*, not idea. Right place for ideas is comment.

Comment: I can't comment!! D: Also, noted. I obviously can't test it, but the little `u` has worked for me in similar situations in the past.

Comment: Not being able to comment as a new user is the worst. I wish they'd change that.

Answer (score 1):

Simply define your strings as Unicode strings using the `u` prefix:

```
return render_template(
        'sample.html',
        title=(u'Härre'),
        year=datetime.now().year,
        message = (u"Härre guut")
)
```

As you've baked non-ASCII into your source code, set the 'coding' bit at the top of your source code. Ensure your editor's character encoding matches the `coding` header.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```